# Animate a predefined list in with matplotlib with known timestep

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, jquery-animate, matplotlib-animation

I generated two location lists (x and y coordinates).
Now I want to animate the movement(changing x and y) element after element.

The FuncAnimation function of matplotlib seems not to work. The animate(i) function usually uses the timedependent changes of x and y; so a function of i. But I know the timestep and I don't want to implement this dependency in the animate function.

So imagine the lists:

- x = [2,5,1,5,2,8,5,8]
- y = [5,3,7,2,0,5,9,3]

with a known timestep

- dt = 0.1 #seconds

How can I animate this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to confirm, you want to animate a single dot and not a whole bunch of dots, right?

Comment: Yes that's kind of right. Imagine a planetary orbit. But in total I have a lot of precalculated Orbits at the same timestep for my universe.